# Endpoints for list and cell feeds of previous spreadsheet revisions

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Using the Google Drive API, I can retrieve a list of previous versions of a google spreadsheet, like so:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId/revisions/revisionId
```

Where `fileID` is the ID of the spreadsheet and revisionId is the revision number.

Each revision returned which has `exportLinks` field with URLs to download these versions as CSV, XLS, etc.

With the google *spreadhseets* API, there are API endpoints for the cell- and row-based representations of the spreadsheets:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/worksheetId/private/full
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/key/worksheetId/private/full
```

Here `key` is the same value as `fileId` above and `worksheetId` is a code for a particular worksheet.

Are there API endpoints to access the list-based feed or cell-based feed for *particular revisions* of a google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Spreadsheets API only operates on the current revision.